# Как заставить производный класс иметь поле(массив, лист и т.д)

Tags: java

У меня есть следующая структура.

Классы AA,DD,CC и т.д наследуются от абстрактного класса A

Класс A в свою очередь имплементируется от Move

Класс А заставляет всех производных иметь метод method.

**Вопрос : Как заставить все производные классы, иметь поле скажем ArrayList list; ?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если поле есть в абстрактном классе, то оно будет и во всех других классах которые от него унаследовались.

Comment: Просто добавьте нужные поля в абстрактный класс и почитайте в чем отличие абстрактного класса от интерфейса

Comment: @VincentVega Пасиб ) я запутался немного в конструкторе A, В общем проблема решена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если поле есть в абстрактном классе, то оно будет и во всех других классах которые от него унаследовались. Просто добавьте нужные поля в абстрактный класс и они будут во всех дочерних классах.